# How to put multiple values of List in a MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, messagebox

First i store multiple values in a list . I want to get all element from list output in a message box but it doesn't work! I tried also many way such that foreach loop under the messagebox but doesn't work. Please help me.[The code is for message box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALR13.jpg) 
[First is my code output and second is target output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyJ8O.jpg)

Comment: Please provide code in text not via a screenshot. Also, elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code may help you to do this:

Let `MyListValues` be the list of strings that you already having, You can use [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method for joining the strings seperated with a delimiter(here i choose `,` as the delimiter). Now see the snippet for this:

```
List<string>MyListValues= new List<string>(){"value 1","value 2","value 3","value 4","value 10","value 11"};
string delimiter=",";
string messageBoxContent=String.Join(delimiter,MyListValues);
MessageBox.Show(messageBoxContent);
```

For your particular example, the best option is Overriding [`.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) method inside the Student class.

Using the class definition may look like the following:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    // rest of properties and declarations
    //Class methods and constructors
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder ObjectString = new StringBuilder();
        ObjectString.AppendLine("Stdent Details");
        ObjectString.AppendLine("Name :" + this.Name);
        ObjectString.AppendLine("ID :" + this.Id);
        ObjectString.AppendLine("Email :" + this.email);
        return ObjectString.ToString();
    }
}
```

And your iterations of the list will be:

```
foreach (Student student in StudentList)
{
    MessageBox.Show(student.ToString());// Shows the message in each iteration
}
```

Or

```
string outputStr=String.Empty;
foreach (Student student in StudentList)
    {
        outputStr +=student.ToString();       
    }
MessageBox.Show(outputStr );// Shows the details of all students in a single Message
```

Comment: Overriding `ToString()` is an ideal option, +1 for `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks . Its Work! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Change your `str` variable inside `foreach` loop to:

```
str += students.studentRegNo+ " " + students.studentName + " " + students.studentEmail+ Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Thanks its Works ;)